# Java: jSpinner: Write to Access Database?

Tags: java

please i need some help on my school assignment: i just want to know the code on how to get the value of jspinner and insert in to ms access database.

here is my code to format it as MM/dd/yyyy:

```
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
model.setCalendarField(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
jSpinner1.setModel(model);
jSpinner1.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

and this is how i tried to insert it to my database:

```
Date value = (Date) jSpinner1.getValue();
String SQLString = "INSERT INTO Table1(Username,Password,Website,DateEncoded)VALUES('"+
    text1+"','"+text2+"','"+text3+"',"+value+")";
```

Comment: when i try to insert the value of jspinner the value i get from it is: Fri Mar 18 09:59:19 SGT 2011 which is supposed to be is MM/dd/yyyy format. i'm getting confused about this value...thanks you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an error message for anybody to know what is going on. One potential problem is that you aren't using a Prepared Statement.  So if text1, text2, text3 or value contain the character "'", your SQL will be wrong.  Also, you don't quote "value".

If this seems like the problem, checkout PreparedStatement:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

The JSpinner.getValue() is returning a Date.  You are seeing the default toString() method of a Date.  You can get the format you want by:

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.format(jSpinner1.getValue());

You should still look at the section on PreparedStatements.  That will make it even easier to work with dates.

Comment: i tried this sir: String SQLString = "INSERT INTO Table1(Username,Password,Website,DateEncoded)VALUES('"+text1+"','"+text2+"','"+text3+"',"+sdf.format(jSpinner1.getValue())+")";                              but i the date that i get inserted a date like this 12/30/1899. i formatted my field inside my ms db as date/time short date. this is the way i formatted my jspinner: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); jSpinner1.setModel(model);
        JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1, "MM/dd/yyyy");
        jSpinner1.setEditor(de); thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value from the spinner, it isn't giving you the displayed string but the value stored in the `SpinnerDateModel`.  You need to use a [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), perhaps one with a custom string specified to an instance of [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and format the date value into a formatted string.  [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) are some examples of using date formatting in Java.

Comment: thank you sir, but can you give me a sample sample code on how to do that? by the way i set my datafield inside my ms access db as date/time. thanks